# SHA1 Java vs Python are not the same

Tags: java, python, cryptography, sha1

I need to translate a piece of python into Java, but when i make a SHA hash, i have not the same result like Python, there is the string :

```
$&).6CXzPHw=2N_+isZK2908069825
```

// Java code

```
private static byte[] getSHA1(byte[] input) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest msdDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    msdDigest.reset();
    msdDigest.update(input, 0, input.length);
    System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary((msdDigest.digest())));
    return msdDigest.digest();
}
```

// Python Code

```
print(sha1(prefix + str(num4).encode('ascii')).digest())
```

Maybe a difference between the byte type ??
Any ideas ?
Thank you

Comment: What code are you using? What result are you getting? What result do you expect?

Comment: What David said, let's see the Python and Java code, inputs and outputs.

Comment: Sorry, i put the code in the question now

Comment: What's `prefix`?

Comment: just the concat of two strings, i made the example : $&).6CXzPHw=2N_+isZK2908069825
For java im giving this string as bytes like this :
 getSHA1((prefix + num4.toString()).getBytes("UTF-8"));

Comment: What are the results that you get?

Comment: Python : [160, 255, 78, 94, 189, 160, 143, 12, 225, 93, 246, 201, 251, 72, 254, 199, 52, 172, 139, 40]
Java : [-38, 57, -93, -18, 94, 107, 75, 13, 50, 85, -65, -17, -107, 96, 24, -112, -81, -40, 7, 9]

I have verified the string is the same in the two context

Comment: If it helps, your Python results are correct. It's the Java result that's unexpected.

Comment: Yes i know, the Python code work, but i don't know why Java make this strange Hash, but the HexDigest is the same but in UpperCase :
For Python : a0ff4e5ebda08f0ce15df6c9fb48fec734ac8b28
For Java : A0FF4E5EBDA08F0CE15DF6C9FB48FEC734AC8B28

Comment: Remove the print statement. Calling digest is destructive and you call it twice - the value that you return from the method is incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is answered by Erwin Bolwidt in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53565583/sha1-java-vs-python-are-not-the-same#comment93997440_53565583):

> **Remove the `print` statement.** Calling `digest` is destructive and you call it twice - the value that you return from the method is incorrect

In addition to that:

- There is no need to call [`reset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html#reset--) on a new [`MessageDigest`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html)
- Call [`update(input)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html#update-byte:A-) instead of [`update(input, 0, input.length)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html#update-byte:A-int-int-)
- Call [`digest(input)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html#digest-byte:A-) instead of [`update(input)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html#update-byte:A-) + [`digest()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html#digest--)

Combined, all the above means that your code should simply be:

```
private static byte[] getSHA1(byte[] input) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    return MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").digest(input);
}
```

*Test*

```
byte[] input = "$&).6CXzPHw=2N_+isZK2908069825".getBytes("US-ASCII");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getSHA1(input)));
```

*Output*

```
[-96, -1, 78, 94, -67, -96, -113, 12, -31, 93, -10, -55, -5, 72, -2, -57, 52, -84, -117, 40]
```

Which is the same as the [Python output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53565583/sha1-java-vs-python-are-not-the-same#comment93997303_53565583), except printed as signed vs unsigned bytes:

```
[160, 255, 78, 94, 189, 160, 143, 12, 225, 93, 246, 201, 251, 72, 254, 199, 52, 172, 139, 40]
```

Answer (score 1):

The Java Cryptographic Architecture the objects that represent the algorithm types such as `MessageDigest` but also `Cipher` and `Mac` are all implementing a scheme that makes it possible to perform piecemeal operations on large amounts of data. They do this by having methods that *update* the internal state and final operations such as sign / verify or  - for `MessageDigest` - a single operation called `digest` with various overloads.

These algorithms also have in common that the state of the object is *reset* to the state directly after initialization when the "final" operation is called. This state is commonly reached after calling an `init` method.

Hash algorithms such as SHA-1 don not require explicit initialization though, so they return to the state directly after instantiation: the state where they did not yet process any data. This way the hash algorithm can be reused to hash another value. This is *slightly more efficient* than instantiating a new object.

From the [JCA developers guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/security/java-cryptography-architecture-jca-reference-guide.htm#JSSEC-GUID-6E9FB890-F011-450E-9EC5-EBB358E1D8A1):

> After the message digest has been calculated, the message digest object is automatically reset and ready to receive new data and calculate its digest. All former state (i.e., the data supplied to update calls) is lost.

So after you called the `digest()` the  object is reset to the state where it hasn't received any data yet. The second call therefore returns the hash over an empty octet string / byte array.

---

So quoted [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#Example_hashes):

```
SHA1("")
gives hexadecimal: da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
```

which is identical to the signed bytes `[-38, 57, -93, -18, 94, 107, 75, 13, 50, 85, -65, -17, -107, 96, 24, -112, -81, -40, 7, 9]`: the value you put in the comments.

---

The correct hash that was printed is indeed

```
 A0FF4E5EBDA08F0CE15DF6C9FB48FEC734AC8B28
```

in uppercase hexadecimals or

```
[160, 255, 78, 94, 189, 160, 143, 12, 225, 93, 246, 201, 251, 72, 254, 199, 52, 172, 139, 40]
```

as an array of *unsigned bytes* in Python. Note that Java uses *signed bytes instead*, so this would equal

```
[-96, -1, 78, 94, -67, -96, -113, 12, -31, 93, -10, -55, -5, 72, -2, -57, 52, -84, -117, 40]
```

---

To calculate this a single call to `MessageDigest#digest(byte[] input): byte[]` would be sufficient, in your case that would be `byte[] digest = msdDigest.digest(input)` after which you could first print out `digest` *and* return the variable holding the byte array later.

---

Note that hashes should still not be used concurrently over multiple threads though; only one hash can be calculated at one time; these classes are not thread-safe.

Comment: Posted this as I'm not agreeing with the wording of Erwin Bolwidt or Andreas. The (state of the) `MessageDigest` object is *not* destructed, it is reset to a known valid state.